# How can I change the default layout directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has all the controllers for the public part of the site scoped under the `Utilisation` module and they all inherit from the `Utilisation::UtilisationController`. I want to make the default layout for these controllers 'utilisation/layouts/*.html.erb'.

I tried via:

```
layout 'utilisation/layouts/application.html.erb'
```

but i get

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layout layouts/utilisation/application ...
```

How can I change the default layout directory ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The path is relative to layouts folder. Try:

```
layout '../utilisation/layouts/application' # without .html.erb is fine
```