# Rails - Render template from a customized/different folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2

Is it possible to call a layout from a location other than app/views/layouts?

I want to use my layout that is located on app/extensions/sites/layouts.

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
render "#{Rails.root}/app/extensions/sites/views/pages/template01.html.erb", :template  => "#{Rails.root}/app/extensions/sites/views/layouts/layout01",
```

Comment: Okay I found the answer from another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885097/how-can-i-change-the-default-layout-directory.

It is now working perfectly on my project.

Comment: you can safely delete this question if there is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the layout inside controllers, like

```
layout "template01"
```

You can also specify the layouts for specific to actions, just follow the link below,

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html